# UNION and subqueries (MySQL)

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm not even sure if title is right, but here is the situation, simplified.

I have one table with adjacency list in it:

```
comments
- id (int)
- parent_id (int)
- depth_level (int)
- ...
```

What I want to do is to query for depth level 0 with order by and a limit and for each of rows returned I want a union with a query that returns same table and an order by and limit but different depth level and I want that subquery to return only rows that are related by parent depth level... and so on. I can have a limit on depth levels if that helps. 
I'm kind of stuck with no reference, like this:

```
select * from ( select * from comments where depth = 0 order by id asc LIMIT 10 ) D0
union all 
select * from ( select * from comments where depth = 1 order by id asc LIMIT 10 ) D1
```

I get unioned rows, but as you can see I'd like D1 to contain only rows which have parent_id with D0 ids... and I want that for multiple levels. Maybe this is the wrong way to do it though. I know it's wishful thinking, but it would be great if somehow I could get for each row if there are more rows than limit provided.

An example:

```
id  parent_id   depth   title
1   0           0       Title 1
2   0           0       Title 2
3   1           1       Title 3
4   1           1       Title 4
5   1           1       Title 5
6   1           1       Title 6
7   1           1       Title 7
8   4           2       Title 8
9   4           2       Title 9
10  4           2       Title 10
11  4           2       Title 11

pseudo:
select * from table where depth = 0 order by id asc limit 1
union 
select * from table where depth = 1 and parent_id from firstQuery.id order by id asc limit 2
union
select * from table where depth = 2 and parent_id from secondQuery.id order by id asc limit 3

result:

id  parent_id   depth   title
1   0           0       Title 1
3   1           1       Title 3
4   1           1       Title 4
8   4           2       Title 8
9   4           2       Title 9
10  4           2       Title 10
```

**edit 2:**

To expand on peterm's answer.

```
(
SELECT *
FROM comments
WHERE depth = 0
ORDER BY id DESC
LIMIT 2
)
UNION ALL
(
  SELECT c.*
    FROM comments c JOIN 
    (
      SELECT id
      FROM comments
      WHERE depth = 0
      ORDER BY id DESC
      LIMIT 2
    ) p ON c.parent_id = p.id
    LIMIT 5
)


id  parent_id   depth   title
1   0           0       Title 1
2   0           0       Title 2
3   1           1       Title 3
4   1           1       Title 4
5   1           1       Title 5
6   1           1       Title 6
7   1           1       Title 7
```

but what I want is to have limit PER parent depth level, not limit in total for depth level. Like this (5 per depth 1 in this example):

```
id  parent_id   depth   title
1   0           0       Title 1
2   0           0       Title 2
3   1           1       Title 3
4   1           1       Title 4
5   1           1       Title 5
6   1           1       Title 6
7   1           1       Title 7
8   2           1       Title 8
9   2           1       Title 9
10  2           1       Title 10
11  2           1       Title 11
12  2           1       Title 12
```

Comment: Can you show some sample data, and what your desired output would look like?

Comment: @Tom I tried to provide an example, not sure if that clears stuff up.

Answer (score 1):

It's ugly but you can do

```
(
  SELECT *
   FROM comments
  WHERE depth = 0
  ORDER BY id
  LIMIT 1
)
UNION ALL
(
  SELECT c.*
   FROM comments c JOIN 
  (
    SELECT id
     FROM comments
    WHERE depth = 0
    ORDER BY id
    LIMIT 1
  ) p ON c.parent_id = p.id
   LIMIT 2
)
UNION ALL
(
  SELECT c.*
   FROM comments c JOIN 
  (
    SELECT c.*
     FROM comments c JOIN 
    (
      SELECT id
       FROM comments
      WHERE depth = 0
      ORDER BY id
      LIMIT 1
    ) q ON c.parent_id = q.id
     LIMIT 2
  ) p ON c.parent_id = p.id
   LIMIT 3
)
-- ORDER BY id
```

Output:

```
| ID | PARENT_ID | DEPTH |    TITLE |
|----|-----------|-------|----------|
|  1 |         0 |     0 |  Title 1 |
|  3 |         1 |     1 |  Title 3 |
|  4 |         1 |     1 |  Title 4 |
|  8 |         4 |     2 |  Title 8 |
|  9 |         4 |     2 |  Title 9 |
| 10 |         4 |     2 | Title 10 |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2fb2e/7)** demo

Comment: This actually fetches depth levels > 0 only from first depth = 0 level. For other depth=0 rows there aren't depth 1,2,3... (I need 6). Though it gave me few ideas, but I'm still not sure. Thanks for effort! edit: limits further down the depths didn't show the rest of the queries, they are there for depth=0 levels. However, limit is only in total per depth, not per parent row. For example if depth=1 has limit 2, then I want not total limit 2 for depth=1, but per depth=0 returned row.